# Laravel 5.6 saving all fields from request and an extra field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am saving all request fields from my model with a one liner in Laravel like this:

```
$imageRequest = Auth::user()->imageRequests()->save(new ImageRequest($request->all()));
```

My model ImageRequest has a bunch of fillables that are in the $request but there is 1 field that is not in the request that I need to save also in the table.

Can I do this in my one liner or do I need to do every fillable seperately like this:

```
$imageRequest = new ImageRequest;

$imageRequest->fillable1 = $request->fillable1
...
$imageRequest->fillableNotInForm = "hello";

$imageRequest->save();
```

Comment: `$imageRequest->fillableNotInForm = "hello";` So, if `hello`(some string literal and not varies for each request) is what you want to add in every row for `fillableNotInForm` column, then set a `DEFAULT` value constraint on this column in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

The `$request->all()` is just an array. You can use `array_merge` to add to it.

```
$imageRequest = Auth::user()->imageRequests()->save(new ImageRequest(array_merge($request->all(), ['index' => 'value'])));
```

With that said, one liners are hard to read. Consider splitting it up in at least 2 lines for readability sake.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe out of scope of this question but how can I get the ID of the item I am currently saving?

Comment: The `save()` function usually returns the saved id. So in your case you should be able to do `$imageRequest->id`. If that doesn't work, I assume `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();` should work fine.

Comment: But the problem is that the value of the field I am trying to add should be the id if the object i am saving with another string attached to it so the save is not finished yet

Comment: You can't get the id before saving the object. There's no way to do that.

Comment: So I should do it in 1 steps? first save the object then update the record?

Comment: You lost me, what record are you trying to update here? I only see one save occurring in your question.

Comment: Sorry, yes let me explain clear. My object has a default primary key the "id" I need to add a second "functional id" that looks like this: id-yyy-mm-dd. So lets say I save the first object I then should have a record with id 1 and functional_id 1-2018-11-07. This functional_id is the "index" in your example and "1-2018-11-07" is the value.

Comment: Oh I see. There's no way to do that without knowing the id first. You'll have to run 2 queries. One to insert the object and the second one to update the previously inserted object.

Comment: Okay, so I should just stick to my previous one liner and make update query or something. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this as well:

```
public function upload(ImageRequest $request) 
{
    Auth::user()->imageRequests()->save($request->merge(['not_in_form' => 'value']));    
}
```